# Arduino IDE 1.6.6, problems with uploading

Tags: ide, arduino

```
/opt/arduino-1.6.6/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I having this problem when I'm trying to upload sketch into arduino. IDE continue writing that uploading. I already tried to `dialout`, that doesn't work in my case. I'm using arduino IDE 1.6.6, because on newer versions I have bigger problems. I have debian Elementary 5.0 Juno on my desktop

Comment: This may be a trivial question, but I must ask: Is libreadline installed in your system?

Comment: @Tagli, yes. It can't access libreadline6, but i have 7th installed. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understood that version of libreadline is matter, so i created symlink from 7th to 6th libreadline version

`cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6`